# Why are battery optimization options getting reset all the time and how to prevent this?

Tags: updates, security, battery, firewall, optimization

They aren't just reset after every restart / upgrade but even without running any update or restarting.

One problem that results from this beyond having to change the settings after update is that firewall apps can get disabled.

After every update the NetGuard firewall was disabled which may be caused by this or be a separate issue.

Additionally, nonessential things/apps like "Facebook Services" can't be set to "Optimize".

For example, "Analytics" is constantly set back to "Don't Optimize", simply overriding my decision to disable it.

How to persist the battery optimization settings?

Comment: By "upgrade" you mean the (monthly) security updates or a major upgrade from e.g. Android 10 to Andorid 11? Which device are you talking about (manufacturer + model)?

Comment: I think both; not just the Android updates – I think the optimization settings were reset after every update including 'Google Play system updates'.

Comment: Play Story System updates - So you are talking about an device with Android 11?

Comment: Consider also mentioning the device model since each brand may implement different battery optimization (ref: [Don't kill my app!](https://dontkillmyapp.com/))